# Heap size that mono develop uses

Tags: xamarin, heap-memory, monodevelop

I am using macOS x64 and I got OutOfMemoryException while my computations. I need 1.8GB.
Hpw can I increase the heap size in Xamarin Studio (mono develop)?

I tried

```
export MONO_GC_PARAMS=max-heap-size=2g
```

but it's now working